# Why this loop is endless

Tags: java, infinite-loop, do-while

I am new to programming.

I was doing a homework, and I got a question about this code:

```
do {
    int i=4;      
} while (true);
```

Why is this loop endless?

Comment: Why is `true` true?

Comment: `true` always evaluates to `true`

Comment: Because it does not have an end condition.

Comment: `int i=4`... int? is this sample from javascript?

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the most basic things in programming - the while loop. The while loop keeps executing as long as its condition is truthy. So, since the condition in your code is `true`, it will run forever because there's nothing else to stop the loop.

Hopefully this will help you understand it:

```
var condition = true;
var i = 5;
do{
  i--; // decrement the value of i
  console.log('i is now', i);
  if (i == 0)
      condition = false;    
} while (condition);

console.log('loop ended');
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9cr0yqp6/

Comment: Wow, a downvote, can't wait to hear AAAALL about it... My answer is definitely the worst, considering the other ones. But it's cool, I got 5 upvotes for the comment.

Comment: That's not true, `while(true){ ... }` does not mean the loop will run forever. You can have an exit condition such as `break`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Are you serious?

Comment: @gab06 Which part did you like the best? :)

Comment: @Shomz Yes, `while(true)` is used all the time with exit conditions. This: "*The while loop keeps executing as long as its condition is truthy. If the condition is true, it will run forever.*" is not true.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek saying it will run "forever" is a good way to explain it to someone is new to programming?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I know that, man. But it's technically irrelevant to the question - the while loop *will* run forever as long as it reaches the end of the cycle and rechecks for the condition. Breaking it this way or another is a different story and I'm not sure we should confuse a beginner programmer with it... yet.

Comment: @gab06 Should I write it will run as long as you don't break out of it, have an error in the code, unplug the power cord (no batteries), etc? I was talking specifically about the while loop here, and as I said to Spencer above, it will repeat every time you let it finish the cycle and the condition remains truthy. Breaking out of the code is something completely different.

Comment: @Shomz hehehe :P. Is good to say it will run forever to a beginner.

Comment: Okay, okay, I've changed that part. Btw. somehow I went from -2 to +1, my incremental loop seems to be working! :D

Comment: +1 That's a good way to put it. I should not of been so picky, and should of considered the OP is a beginner.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thank you, I always try *not* to overcomplicate things for beginners... One block at a time.

Comment: @gab06 I can't, StackOverflow won't let me! ;) Ha, it's +2 now :D

Answer (score 0):

you have not exit method. you never set the loop to false.

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop because you do not have a condition to exit the loop.

True will always be true so the loop continues to execute until your condition is false (which cannot happen).

This loop while infinitely create a local variable named i and then assign the value 4 to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Java, not JavaScript.

Loops continue to loop when the condition remains true.

Example of a loop that ends and an explanation why:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

Each iteration `i` increases by 1 (due to `i++`), and once the condition (being `i < 5`) is no longer true, the loop breaks out and ends.

In your loop, true will always be true.

Comment: It can be C, C++ too :P

Comment: Given that it's homework and given he's probably a student I'd wager Java, but you're absolutely correct.  And he tagged JavaScript which lead me to believe he meant Java (because this isn't JS).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps to explain why the loop is endless, let's look at one that ends:

```
var i = 4;
do{
  i = i + 1;
} while (i < 6);
```

This loop will iterate while it turns `i` to 5, then 6, and that will make the condition in the `while` statement false, which ends the loop.

If you have `while (true)` instead, the condition will never be false, and the loop never ends.

Answer (score 0):

The "while" loop is endless because you set the condition to true.